# How to display all data from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm making an app that will let users add their school subjects.
Before i continue let me give you my code:

MainActivity:

```
    package cannon.gaming.mymarks;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView textSubject;
    String SUBJECT, PASS;
    Context ctx =  this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });*/

        Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        textSubject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubject);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showInputDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void showInputDialog() {

        // get prompts.xml view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SUBJECT = editText.getText().toString();
                        PASS = "0";
                        DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
                        DB.putInformation(DB, SUBJECT, PASS);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Subject added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

TableData:

```
package cannon.gaming.mymarks;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

/**
 * Created by Asuspc on 01/07/2015.
 */
public class TableData {

    public TableData()
    {

    }

    public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns
    {
        public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
        public static final String USER_PASS = "user_pass";
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_info";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "reg_info";
    }

}
```

DatabaseOperations:

```
package cannon.gaming.mymarks;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Asuspc on 01/07/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int database_version = 1;
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+ TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS+" TEXT);";
    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Database created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb)
    {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Table created");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2)
    {

    }
    public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop,String name, String pass)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
        long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "One row inserted");
    }
    public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS};
        Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return CR;
    }
}
```

Now let me explain.
When I press the "buttonAdd" button it will let me enter the subject name obviously, and save it in database.

But what I can't make is, I want to display all database on MainActivity.
And it should be like this:

- names of subjects on the left side,
- average of those subjects on the right side (the string PASS should be that average, that's why it is 0 when you first add the subject).

And I want to make each of those subjects clickable, so when you click it it should show you all marks from that subject and let you add or remove them.

Now, I guess, displaying data shouldn't be so hard, but still I need your help.
But making each subject clickable I really have no idea how.
And each subject having its own marks, I don't know, does it mean new activity for every new subject or new database or what?

EDIT:

MainActivity now:

```
package cannon.gaming.mymarks;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String SUBJECT, PASS;
    Context CTX =  this;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });*/

        Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        displayListView();
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showInputDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void showInputDialog() {

        // get prompts.xml view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SUBJECT = editText.getText().toString();
                        PASS = "0";
                        DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
                        DB.putInformation(DB, SUBJECT, PASS);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Subject added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        displayListView();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void displayListView()
    {
        DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
        Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
        CR.moveToFirst();
        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME,
                TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS
        };
        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.code,
                R.id.name,
        };
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.activity_login,
                CR,
                columns,
                to,
                0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display data, you should use ListView and CursorAdapter.
Here is sample code for you: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

In that sample code, you can see:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
     int position, long id) {
   // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
   Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

   // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
   String countryCode = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("code"));
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
});
```

OnItemClickListener will help you to handle when a item in the listview is clicked.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have been trying to fix it with that link you gave me, now i have this error :java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cannon.gaming.mymarks/cannon.gaming.mymarks.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: i edited the question above and added how my MainActivity code looks now

Comment: Just FIXED it, Thanks though :D

Comment: i have another problem now, how do i add new column to specific row?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to add new column to your database table?

Comment: i don't know how to let user insert new marks, i mean i don't know where to save them, i thought new column for every mark is a good idea but if you have a better solution i'll be happy to hear it

Comment: If you want to save user mark permanently, you should add a column in DB table. If you just want to save it in current activity and don't want it be saved after quitting the activity, you just need to create a list of boolean to store.

Comment: yes, i want to save them permanently, do i need a column for each mark or can i just put every mark in one column and then calculate average from that column

Comment: I think that you should create another table in your db to store the marks of each subject. In that table, you should add preference to subject table. You can query all marks of a subject using the subject id. About the average value of each subject, I think you should have a column in subject table to store it and that average will be recalculated each time there is a mark is inserted or removed.